# TCP communication between localhost client and server has corrupted data

Tags: delphi, serialization, tcp, h.264

I am trying to stream raw h264 video packets from a (IcsOverbyte) Server (TWSocketServer) to a Client(TWSocket) however I've been having some trouble trying to properly assemble the messages.

Before going into my question I just wanted to say that I've confirmed that the .h264 data is valid, after I serialize my message I deserialize it and save the video-packet data part into a file and play it with VLC, the file is playable with no issues. That way I also confirmed that my Serialize/Deserialize routine is correct (both server and client have the same source for the types and ser/des routine).

My message is like so ->

```
  TMessageHeader = packed record
    MessageID: UInt32;
    TotalSize: UInt32; {Meaning HeaderSize + Payload}
  end;

  TMediaDataMessage = record
    Header: TMessageHeader;
    Channel: UInt32;
    Stream: UInt32;
    MediaType: Byte; {0 - Video, 1 - Audio}
    Data: TArray<Byte>;
    function FromBytes(pBytes: TArray<Byte>): Boolean;
    function ToBytes: TArray<Byte>;
    function GetSize: UInt32;
  end;
```

On the client-side I have a message assembly routine like this...

```
procedure TfrmMain.HandleDataAvailable(pSender: TObject; ErrCode: Word);
var
  vRcvdCount: Integer;
  vBytes: TBytes;
  vMessageTotalSize: UInt32;
  vOffset: UInt32;
begin
  {$POINTERMATH ON}
  if ErrCode <> 0 then
    Exit;

  if pSender = nil then
    Exit;

  SetLength(vBytes, 65536);
  vRcvdCount := fTCPClient.Receive(@vBytes[0], 65536);
  vOffset := 0;

  try
    if fRemainingDataSize > 0 then
    begin
      if vRcvdCount >= fRemainingDataSize then
      begin
        fCurrentBuf.Write(vBytes[vOffset], fRemainingDataSize);
        Inc(vOffset, fRemainingDataSize);
        Dec(vRcvdCount, fRemainingDataSize);
        fRemainingDataSize := 0;
        SetHandleMessage(fIdx.ToString + 'Sync');
      end
      else
      begin
        fCurrentBuf.Write(vBytes[vOffset], vRcvdCount);
        Dec(fRemainingDataSize, vRcvdCount);
      end;
    end;
  except
    reLog.Lines.Add('Error sync');
  end;

  try
    while (vRcvdCount > 0) do
    begin
      vMessageTotalSize := PUInt32(@vBytes[vOffset + 4])^;

      if vRcvdCount >= vMessageTotalSize then
      begin
        fCurrentBuf.Write(vBytes[vOffset], vMessageTotalSize);
        Inc(vOffset, vMessageTotalSize);
        Dec(vRcvdCount, vMessageTotalSize);
        SetHandleMessage('Loop');
      end
      else
      begin
        fCurrentBuf.Write(vBytes[vOffset], vRcvdCount);
        fRemainingDataSize := vMessageTotalSize - vRcvdCount;
        vRcvdCount := 0;
      end;
    end;
  except
    reLog.Lines.Add('Loop');
  end;

  //fTcpClient.Flush;
end;
```

FYI the exceptions never occur.

And this is the SetHandleMessage procedure

```
procedure TfrmMain.SetHandleMessage(pSort: string);
var
  vMsgBytes: TArray<Byte>;
  vMessageID: UInt32;
begin
  fCurrentBuf.Position := 0;
  SetLength(vMsgBytes, fCurrentBuf.Size);
  fCurrentBuf.Read(vMsgBytes[0], fCurrentBuf.Size);
  fCurrentBuf.Clear;
  vMessageID := PUInt32(@vMsgBytes[0])^;
  HandleMessage(vMessageID, vMsgBytes, pSort);
end;
```

I've been chasing my own tail for a while now I can't seem to pinpoint what is the issue.

I've also tried just streaming the raw .h264 to the client and save it to file and it works as well...

It seems the only thing that could be wrong is the message assembly routine.

Edit:. Decided to add the serialization functions.

```
function TMediaDataMessage.FromBytes(pBytes: TArray<Byte>): Boolean;
var
  vLen: Integer;
  vOffset: Integer;
  vArrSize: UInt32;
begin
  vOffset := 0;

  Move(pBytes[vOffset], PByte(@Header.MessageId)[0], Sizeof(Header.MessageID));
  Inc(vOffset, Sizeof(Header.MessageID));
  Move(pBytes[vOffset], PByte(@Header.TotalSize)[0], Sizeof(Header.TotalSize));
  Inc(vOffset, Sizeof(Header.TotalSize));
  Move(pBytes[vOffset], PByte(@Channel)[0], Sizeof(Channel));
  Inc(vOffset, Sizeof(Channel));
  Move(pBytes[vOffset], PByte(@Stream)[0], Sizeof(Stream));
  Inc(vOffset, Sizeof(Stream));
  Move(pBytes[vOffset], PByte(@MediaType)[0], Sizeof(MediaType));
  Inc(vOffset, Sizeof(MediaType));

  Move(pBytes[vOffset], PByte(@vArrSize)[0], Sizeof(vArrSize));
  Inc(vOffset, Sizeof(vArrSize));

  if vArrSize <> 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(Data, vArrSize);
    Move(pBytes[vOffset], Data[0], vArrSize);
  end;

  Exit(True);
end;
```

```
function TMediaDataMessage.GetSize: UInt32;
begin
  Result := (Sizeof(uInt32) *2) + Sizeof(Channel) + Sizeof(Stream) +
    Sizeof(MediaType) + Sizeof(UInt32) + Length(Data);
end;
```

```
function TMediaDataMessage.ToBytes: TArray<Byte>;
var
  vSize: UInt32;
  vOffset: UInt32;
  vLen: UInt32;
begin
  vSize := Self.GetSize;

  SetLength(Result, vSize);
  vOffset := 0;

  Move(Self.Header.MessageID, Result[vOffset], Sizeof(Self.Header.MessageID));
  Inc(vOffset, Sizeof(Self.Header.MessageID));
  Move(Self.Header.TotalSize, Result[vOffset], Sizeof(Self.Header.TotalSize));
  Inc(vOffset, Sizeof(Self.Header.TotalSize));

  Move(Self.Channel, Result[vOffset], Sizeof(Self.Channel));
  Inc(vOffset, Sizeof(Self.Channel));
  Move(Self.Stream, Result[vOffset], Sizeof(Self.Stream));
  Inc(vOffset, Sizeof(Self.Stream));

  Move(Self.MediaType, Result[vOffset], Sizeof(Self.MediaType));
  Inc(vOffset, Sizeof(Self.MediaType));

  vLen := Length(Self.Data);
  Move(vLen, Result[vOffset], Sizeof(UInt32));
  Inc(vOffset, Sizeof(UInt32));
  if vLen > 0 then
    Move(Self.Data[0], Result[vOffset], vLen);
end;
```

Comment: Just because it plays with VLC doesn't mean the file is correct - [VLC's key feature is to get the most out of incomplete or corrupted files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player#Formats). Also try "streaming" with a test file whose content you can easily read and recognize (instead of video data, f.e. use poetic text or such), so you see after message part lengths of 65536 bytes or such if they're really seamless put together or if the start/end looks different. Likewise use only `>` as operator, not `>=` - because it's still suspicious if you get more data than expected!

Comment: Your TMediaDataMessage contain a dynamic array (TArray<Byte>). You don't show how you use TMediaDataMessage but for sure you can't send a dynamic type because it make use of a pointer whose value is useless for the other side of communication.

Comment: @fpiette I use a 32 bit unsigned integer before arrays so the client-side can tell how much data there is before the next field. Again the first 4-5 seconds of video play fine.

Comment: @AmigoJack Every time the server tries to send a big message 60000 bytes > the last four bytes of the message in the server are different from the last four bytes of the message in the client. For smaller messages like that last four bytes are equal.

Comment: Is the buffer size sufficient? 65536 bytes could be the limit causing corruption. Could you add log output to see the actual / expected length?

Comment: @mjn HandleDataAvailable is called again if there's more data to be read from the socket. I did add a log output and the size is right but the data is wrong.

Comment: So you don't send TMediaDataMessage as a whole. You send the first part up to Data member and then you send data member independently. Right ?

Comment: @fpiette I have a serialization function that packet everything into a single byte array. And I call the send function passing the byte array as parameter (the pointer to its first element)

Comment: _"The size is right but the data is wrong"_ Anyway to provide a link to a testable copy of your bytes (maybe 10 seconds of h264)? I don't use Delphi but I can try spot the mistakes in the bytes and advise about (then you could change the Delphi code as needed).

Comment: @VC.One Sure.
https://filebin.net/84okrbeo3fewyd1r/Client.h264
https://filebin.net/84okrbeo3fewyd1r/Client.txt
https://filebin.net/84okrbeo3fewyd1r/Server.h264
https://filebin.net/84okrbeo3fewyd1r/Server.txt

Comment: The payload length is already known after reading the header, correct? So actually the client only has to read a known number of bytes from the server? And while still receiving data, the client wants to pass the data to some video player?

Comment: @mjn That's the idea, yes. But I just can't figure out what am I doing wrong in the client-side, as I have said I exclued any issue on server-side because just before calling Client.Send I deserialize the packet and save the data field to a file, and it plays just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...
I had to set vRcvdCount to 0 in the first else statement.

Looks like this now ->

```
procedure TfrmMain.HandleDataAvailable(pSender: TObject; ErrCode: Word);
var
  vRcvdCount: Integer;
  vBytes: TBytes;
  vMessageTotalSize: UInt32;
  vOffset: UInt32;
begin
  {$POINTERMATH ON}
  if ErrCode <> 0 then
    Exit;

  if pSender = nil then
    Exit;

  SetLength(vBytes, 65536);
  vRcvdCount := fTCPClient.Receive(@vBytes[0], 65536);
  vOffset := 0;

  try
    if fRemainingDataSize > 0 then
    begin
      if vRcvdCount >= fRemainingDataSize then
      begin
        fCurrentBuf.Write(vBytes[vOffset], fRemainingDataSize);
        Inc(vOffset, fRemainingDataSize);
        Dec(vRcvdCount, fRemainingDataSize);
        fRemainingDataSize := 0;
        SetHandleMessage(fIdx.ToString + 'Sync');
      end
      else
      begin
        fCurrentBuf.Write(vBytes[vOffset], vRcvdCount);
        Dec(fRemainingDataSize, vRcvdCount);
        vRcvdCount := 0; \\ Add this here!!!
      end;
    end;
  except
    reLog.Lines.Add('Error sync');
  end;

  try
    while (vRcvdCount > 0) do
    begin
      vMessageTotalSize := PUInt32(@vBytes[vOffset + 4])^;

      if vRcvdCount >= vMessageTotalSize then
      begin
        fCurrentBuf.Write(vBytes[vOffset], vMessageTotalSize);
        Inc(vOffset, vMessageTotalSize);
        Dec(vRcvdCount, vMessageTotalSize);
        SetHandleMessage('Loop');
      end
      else
      begin
        fCurrentBuf.Write(vBytes[vOffset], vRcvdCount);
        fRemainingDataSize := vMessageTotalSize - vRcvdCount;
        vRcvdCount := 0;
      end;
    end;
  except
    reLog.Lines.Add('Loop');
  end;

  //fTcpClient.Flush;
end;
```